# How to resolve the custom messages using GraphQL and ES6

Tags: node.js, mongodb, es6-promise, graphql

I am newly working with GraphQL and ES6 and i have a problem to resolve the custom messages like "User already exist" or "Email already exist".How i want to resolve this type of messages in response.When using reject("Email already exist") i am getting the response like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "Signup": null
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Email already exist",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I just want to print message as "Email already exist", not the entire report. Please suggest me accordingly. Thank you